# generics - constrain to same subtype

Tags: generics, dart

Lets have a function `set` as below:

```
abstract class Animal{}

class Cat extends Animal{}

class Dog extends Animal{}

void set<T extends Animal>(final T tcat, final T tdog)
```

This works fine, but sometimes one could like restriction to same subtype e.g.

`void set<T extends Animal>(final T tcatA, final T tcatB)`

So the compiler/runtime would not accept:

`set(new Cat(), new Dog());`

But accept:

`set(new Cat(), new Cat());` and
`set(new Dog(), new Dog());`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some clarification was added by Danny.

Found a java inspired solution, added a constrain between the two generic parameters. Seems to work so far.

`void set<T extends Animal, S extends T>(final T t, final S s)`

Comment: This tricks inference because the two arguments are inferred separately, and the inference of `S` happens after `T` has already been found. It's not perfect, though, there are some sharp edges. If `Cheshire` is a subclass of `Cat`, then `set(Cheshire(), Cat())` fails, but  `set(Cat(), Cheshire())` succeeds.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, actually letting first parameter decide type of the next is the behavior I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, but even if it was I don't think it'd stop what you're trying to prevent. Consider this:

```
Animal a = new Cat();
Animal b = new Dog();
set(a, b); // Works fine, both types are Animal
```

This is what's happening with your example - `T` is inferred as `Animal`. If you add `print(T)` to your function and call it with a Cat and a Dog, it will output `Animal`.

You can see similar behaviour here:

```
void check<T>(final T a, final T b) {
  print(T);
}

void main() {
  check(true, 1); // Prints "Object"
}
```

While it may seem surprising at a glance, I think it makes sense since you can always pass a subtype in where a supertype is expected.